# Symmetry of a time-dependent Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem

> How do I get the group of symmetries and the constant of motion of $L=\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2}m+V(x+ct)$ where c is a constant?

When I tried to solve it, it was to look for shifts in $x$ and $ct$ under which $L$ is invariant. I did
$$x\rightarrow x+A,$$
$$ct\rightarrow ct+B.$$
$\therefore A+B=0$ so that invariance is satisfied.

But I don't know what to do from here.